# TEXTAREA assign html content to value -- Not show html tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the html file content and want to assign it to the TEXTAREA value.
But how to **not show** html tag??

```
<TEXTAREA id="Terms"></TEXTAREA>
<script>
$.get("/mobile/en/html/tnc/apply.html", function(tnc) {
   var elem3 = document.getElementById('Terms');
   if (elem3){ elem3.value = tnc; }
});
</script>
```

apply.html

```
<html>
.......
</html>
```

As it has below function:

```
function disableDeclarationCheckbox() {
                var form = document.forms['CardForm'];
                var ta = document.getElementById('Terms');
                if (ta!=null && ta.scrollHeight <= ta.offsetHeight){
                    if (form){ if (form.cardTermsCheckbox){
                        form.cardTermsCheckbox.checked = false;
                        form.cardTermsCheckbox.disabled = false;
                    }}
                    return;
                }
                if (form){ if (form.cardTermsCheckbox){
                    form.cardTermsCheckbox.checked = false;
                    form.cardTermsCheckbox.disabled = true;
                }}
                $('textarea#Terms').on('scroll', function() {
                    if (this.scrollHeight <= (this.scrollTop+this.offsetHeight)) {
                        if (form){ if (form.cardTermsCheckbox){
                            form.cardTermsCheckbox.disabled = false;
                        }}
                    }
                });
                return;
            }
```

Comment: textarea is not designed to do that, use a div and add contenteditable attribute

Comment: As I have the function disableCheckBox(), it works on TEXTAREA. How to apply to <DIV> ???

Comment: `disabled` is an attribute that belongs to certain form controls of which of course `<div>` is not. There are ways to simulate being disabled through CSS (ex. `pointer-events:none; opacity:.3`)

Answer (score 0):

Text areas just show text, they don't interpret HTML.

Instead of a text area, use a div, like this:

```
<div id="Terms"></div>
<script>
$.get("/mobile/en/html/tnc/apply.html", function(tnc) {
   var elem3 = document.getElementById('Terms');
   if (elem3){ elem3.innerHTML = tnc; }
});
</script>
```

If you need users to be able to type into the div, you could change it to

```
<div id="Terms" contenteditable="true"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use a `<span>` in place of `<textarea>`.

```
<span id='Terms'></span>
```